# Get results from fetchXml using new retrieveMultipleRecords (Client API reference)

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-webapi

Having trouble figuring how to get results from the following fetchXml using the new retrieveMultipleRecords (Client API reference):

```
var request = "<fetch output-format='xml-platform' distinct='true' version='1.0' mapping='logical'>" +
"<entity name='msdyn_incidenttype'>" +
"<attribute name='msdyn_name'/>" +
"<attribute name='createdon'/>" +
"<attribute name='msdyn_estimatedduration'/>" +
"<attribute name='msdyn_incidenttypeid'/>" +
"<order attribute='msdyn_name' descending='false'/>" +
"<link-entity name='product' link-type='inner' alias='ag' from='productid' to='aka_productfamilyid'>" +
"<link-entity name='msdyn_customerasset' link-type='inner' alias='ah' from='msdyn_product' to='productid'>" +
"<filter type='and'>" +
"<condition attribute='msdyn_customerassetid' operator='eq' uiname='' uitype='msdyn_customerasset' value='${custAssetId}'/>" +
"</filter>" +
"</link-entity>" +
"</link-entity>" +
"</entity>" +
"</fetch>";
```

I use the above fetchXml with the new client api reference as follows:

```
var results = Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("msdyn_incidenttype",request).then(
  function success(result) {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
          console.log(result.entities[i]);
      }
      console.log("Next page link: " + result.nextLink);
      // perform additional operations on retrieved records
  },
  function (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      // handle error conditions
  }
```

The document I read (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/retrievemultiplerecords) states that the second parameter are options and if is fetchXml (as I am using) then to specify it there.  However Im receiving the following errors in console:

> HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the
>   server due to invalid syntax. (XHR)GET -
>   https://dev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/msdyn_incidenttypes?fetch
>   output-format='xml-platform' distinct='true' version='1.0'
>   mapping='logical'>entity name='msdyn_incidenttype'>attribute
>   name='msdyn_name'/>attribute name='createdon'/>attribute
>   name='msdyn_estimatedduration'/>attribute
>   name='msdyn_incidenttypeid'/>order attribute='msdyn_name'
>   descending='false'/>link-entity name='product' link-type='inner'
>   alias='ag' from='productid' to='aka_productfamilyid'>link-entity
>   name='msdyn_customerasset' link-type='inner' alias='ah'
>   from='msdyn_product' to='productid'>filter type='and'>condition
>   attribute='msdyn_customerassetid' operator='eq' uiname=''
>   uitype='msdyn_customerasset'
>   value='${custAssetId}'/>/filter>/link-entity>/link-entity>/entity>/fetch>

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `"?fetchXml="` in front like below:

```
Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("msdyn_incidenttype", "?fetchXml= " + request).then(
                function success(result) {
                    return result;
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log("failed with error: ", error);
                    return null;
                }
            );
```

> **options**
>   OData system query options or FetchXML query to retrieve your data.
>
> - Following system query options are supported: $select, $top, $filter, $expand, and $orderby.
> - To specify a FetchXML query, use the `fetchXml` attribute to specify the query.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/retrievemultiplerecords#parameters)

Comment: Yup.  Just found it as I seen your answer.  I used the following:   var request = "?fetchXml=" + encodeURIComponent(request);